# Ruby on Rails: testing if ActiveRecord results include a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Afternoon,

Lets say I have gather a random selection of users:

User.find(:all, :limit => 10, :order => "rand()")

Now from these results, I want to see if the user with the ID of 3 was included in the results, what would be the best way of finding this out?

I thought about Array.include? but that seems to be a dead end for me.

Thanks

JP

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
users = User.find(:all, :limit => 10, :order => "rand()")
users.any? {|u| u.id == 3}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
assert random_users.include?(User.find 3), "Not found!"
```

Active record objects are considered equal if they have equal ids.  Array#include? respects the objects defined equality via the `==` method.

Answer (score 0):

User.find(:all, :limit => 10, :order => "rand()").any? { |u| u.id == 3 }

This will save you from doing another find.